# flutter: i can not build android apk

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

**I'm trying to create my APK app but it fails and prints this error in android studio terminal:**

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...  

                  



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: E:\flutter\2021\my_flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar.
         > Transform's input file does not exist: E:\flutter\2021\my_flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 19s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          562.4s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

**in the debugging mode the app work!!**
***I hope you can help me with the solution to fix the error***

Comment: try : on terminal run the command - flutter clean   .  then run flutter build apk

Comment: First: Run `flutter clean` and try building again. Chances are it will work this time. Second: If it still isn't building, follow the URL that the error message links and follow the instructions to fix the issue.